# docker container port accessed from another container

Tags: docker, mapping, containers, port

I have a container1 running a service1 on port1

also

I have a container2 running a service2 on port2

How can I access service2:port2 from service1:port1?

I mention that the container are linked together.

I ask if there is a way to do it without accessing the docker0 IP (where the port is visible)

thanks

Comment: assuming service2 has ran before service1, and linked as 's2' upon start of service1, you should be able to make a call to s2:<port> within service1?

Comment: hi @zatta! actually that is not possible

Comment: May I ask what command do you run service1 with?

Comment: service 1 is rabbitmq:5672 and service2 is php trying to connect to rabbitmq

Comment: So I assume they are on same machine, you say providing IP works but not the linked name 'rabbitmq' as you even started service2 as: docker ... --link rabbitmq:rabbitmq .... right?  I also assume service1 run as: docker  --name rabbitmq ...

Comment: use `--name` and `--link` options. Run rabbitmq with `--name rabbitmq` and link rabbitmq to php container by running php container with `--link rabbitmq:rabbitmq`. This way you can access rabbitmq container from php container just using container's name `rabbitmq`, without ip address & port :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred solution is to place both containers on the same network, use the build-in dns discovery to reach the other node by name, and you'll be able to access them by the container port, not the host published port. By CLI, that looks like:

```
docker network create testnet
docker run -d --net testnet --name web nginx
docker run -it --rm --net testnet busybox wget -qO - http://web
```

The busybox shows a sample client container connecting to the nginx container with the name web, over port 80. Note that this port didn't need to be published to be reachable by other containers.

Setting up multi-container environments with their own network is a common task for docker-compose, so I'd recommend looking into this tool if you find yourself doing this a lot.

Comment: Could I access from host ip and published port?

Comment: @FalconIA that would expose a port for a potentially internal only application to the greater network, maybe even the internet. It also bounces the request through a hairpin NAT which sometimes fails, subjects it to the host IP tables, and typically relays through the userspace proxy. So less than ideal but may work.