# Access Docker postgres container from another container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to make a portable solution to having my application container connect to a postgres container.  By 'portable' I mean that I can give the user two `docker run` commands, one for each container, and they will always work together.

I have a postgres docker container running on my local PC, and I run it like this,

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -v $(pwd)/datadir:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty -d postgres:11
```

and I am able to access it from a python flask app, using the address `127.0.0.1:5432`.

I put the python app in a docker container as well, and I am having trouble connecting to the postgres container.

Address `127.0.0.1:5432` does not work.

Address `172.17.0.2:5432` **DOES** work (172.17.0.2 is the address of the docker container running postgres).  However I consider this not portable because I can't guarantee what the postgres container IP will be.

I am aware of the `--add-host` flag, but it is also asking for the host-ip, which I want to be the localhost (127.0.0.1).  Despite several hits on `--add-host` I wasn't able to get that to work so that the final docker run commands can be the same on any computer they are run on.

I also tried this: [docker container port accessed from another container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318770/docker-container-port-accessed-from-another-container)

My situation is that the postgres and myApp will be containers running on the same computer.  I would prefer a non-Docker compose solution.

Comment: In your case, create an user define network - maybe a brigde network -> Join your container in that net work. Then your container can call each other via container name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comment from [Truong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7247053/truong-dang) had me try that approach (again) and I got it working.  Here are my steps in case it helps out another.  The crux of the problem was needing one container to address another container in a way that was static (didn't change).  Using user defined network was the answer, because you can name a container, and thus reference that container IP by that name.

My steps,

```
docker network create mynet
docker run --net mynet --name mydb -v $(pwd)/datadir:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty -d postgres:11
```

Now the IP address of the postgres database is `mydb`, and all the ports of this container are exposed to any other container running in this network.

Now add the front end app,

```
docker run --net mynet -ti -p 80:80 -v mydockerhubaccount/myapp
```